# Implications of the Finite dimensionality of $V_1\times V_2\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times V_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Is the following Proof Correct?

If So any suggestions on how to make the argument more formal

**Theorem.** Given that $V_1,V_2,...,V_n$ are vector spaces such that $V_1\times V_2\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times V_n$ is finite dimensional then $\forall j\in\{1,2,3,...,n\}(V_j$ is finite dimensional).

**Proof.**  Assume that the vector space $\mathcal{V} = V_1\times V_2\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times V_n$ is finite dimensional, and that $j\in I = \{1,2,3,...,n\}$ where $j$ is arbitrary now consider the vector space $\mathcal{W}$
defined as follows $$\mathcal{W} = W_1\times W_2\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times W_j\cdot\cdot\cdot\times W_n$$ where $W_j = V_j$ and $\forall i\in I(i\neq j\implies W_i = \{0\})$. It is not difficult to see that $\mathcal{W}\leqslant\mathcal{V}$ and is therefore finite dimensional which implies that $V_j$ must also be finite dimensional since our choice of $j$ was arbitrary it follows that for each $k = 1,2,3\ .\ .\ .\ ,n$ the vector space $V_k$ is finite dimensional.

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea is exactly correct. I would say $W \leq V$ is a little bit vague. Another method would be to determine exactly the basis for $V$ using the definition of direct product, and use the same idea to claim a basis for a vector space isomorphic to $V_j$ contained in $V$ (more or less as you have done.)